# How to point domain to different server without changing the nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to point a domain name to the server hosting my website. I generally do this by changing the domain nameservers to the server hosting the site. However, I have recently learned that my domain registrar gives free wildcard ssl certificates as long as you are using their nameservers. So, I would like to control my DNS through the domain registrar, but have the domain and sub-domains point to the server hosting the site. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I would like to control my DNS through the domain registrar, but
> have the domain and sub-domains point to the server hosting the site.
> Is there a way to do this?

Yes. Create the appropriate A or CNAME records at your DNS host (the registrar) for the web server/web site.